# Should [benchmarking] and [performance] tags be synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I just created a "performance" tag for [this question](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/q/716/292).
I went to see if this tag could be added to other questions, and thought about [this one](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/q/361/292), that happens to already have a "benchmarking" tag.

Should those two tags be synonyms?

Answer (score 7):

[benchmarking](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/benchmarking) largely means evaluation by comparisons. [performance](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance) does not imply comparisons. In addition, benchmarking evaluates accuracy in addition to performance, I think. They are not synonyms.